# Displaying 'Instance of class_name' instead of data

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-http

I am trying to get the data from an API, but when executing the following the code I am getting the response as only 'Instance of class Survey' but not the actual data in the API. Here is the code I am using:

```
Future GetSurvey() async {
    var response = await http.get(
      url,
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json"
      }
    );
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      var data = convertoJson['Item'];
      print(Questions.fromjson(data));*/

      Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
      var data = map['Item'];
      Survey survey = new Survey.fromjson(data);
      print(survey.questions);


    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }



  }

}

class Questions{
  String questions;

  Questions({this.questions});

  factory Questions.fromjson(Map<String, dynamic> json){


    //var questionfromjson = json['question'];
    //List<String> questionslist = new List<String>.from(questionfromjson);

    return Questions(
      questions: json['question']
    );
  }

}

class Survey{
  String surveyid;
  List<Questions> questions;

  Survey({this.surveyid,this.questions});

  factory Survey.fromjson(Map<String, dynamic> json){

    var list = json['QUESTIONS'] as List;
    print(list.runtimeType);

    List<Questions> questionslist = list.map((e) => Questions.fromjson(e)).toList();

    return Survey(
      surveyid: json['OS_ID'],
      questions: questionslist
    );
  }

}
```

Following is the format of the API:

```
{
    "Item":
    {
        "OS_ID": "759",
        "QUESTIONS":[
        {
            "rule":,
            "question": "How much is the value"
        },
        {
            "rule":,
            "question": "Describe the view"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post an [mcve]. Your code does not compile and even if it would, it would print a message different from the one you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to worry, your code is fine. Just need to override `toString()` function inside your model class..

```
@override
  String toString() {
    return 'questions{questions: $questions}';
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. I am able to get one question but it is still coming in json format, how do I convert it to string format?

Comment: It is showing like: questions{questions: How much is the value}

Comment: You can modify it the way you want. Like if you return `$questions` than you can get the questions only

Comment: Okay. Thank you.

Comment: if you have found your answer than consider this as correct and give an up vote :)

Comment: I have less than 15 reputations so my vote won't show

Comment: Okay, Got it. Done :)